# scala for loop value is not a member of Int

Tags: java, scala, pug

I'm getting a `value map is not a member of Int` error and I'm not sure what that means so I can't figure it out.

I have two pages, scala.html, and scala.jade. The issue occurs when a template.scala file is created. Here is the code for both pages that is creating the issue:

```
scala.html
@page.getProduct().getRichContent().size()
@for(i <- page.getProduct().getRichContent().size()) {
<p>@page.getProduct().getRichContent.get(i)</p>
}

scala.jade
p @page.getProduct().getRichContent().size()
| @for (i <- page.getProduct().getRichContent().size()) {
p @page.getProduct().getRichContent.size()
}
```

The error thrown is:

```
value map is not a member of int
for(i <- page.getProduct().getRichContent().size()) yield /*74.63*/
                                                ^
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
for(i <- 0 to page.getProduct().getRichContent().size())
```

Is what are you looking for.

Comment: Thanks, annoying that it was such a little thing.

Comment: You probably want `until` not `to` unless you want to index the `size`th element (which I would suspect is off the end of the collection...).